# Prove that a language is not regular

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

I want to prove that $L$ is not regular:
$$L = \{ww^Rv \mid |w|\ge1 , |v|\ge 0\},$$ where the alphabet contains at least two symbols.

Can someone prove it?

I prefer to use "Pumping Lemma for Regular Languages" to prove it, but I think that's somehow impossible!

Would someone help me, please?

Comment: What is the alphabet?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott result and proof should be same for any alphabet with > 1 symbol.

Comment: Nonetheless {0,1} is usually implied.

Comment: Yes you need >1 symbol (otherwise $L$ is regular).

Comment: @djechlin: I’m aware that all that matters is that the alphabet have at least two symbols, but the OP may not be. \\ In elementary courses you can’t assume that it’s $\{0,1\}$ even if you know that it’s a two-element alphabet: very often it’s $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: To answer one of the implicit questions: 
A direct application of the pumping lemma *is* impossible, i.e., this (irregular) language does have a pumping length: $3$.

Let $ww^Rv\in L$ be a word of length $\ge 3$.

* If $|w|>1$, say $w=xw'$ with $|x|=1$, $|w'|\ge 1$, then $x^nw'w^Rv\in L$ for all $n\in\Bbb N_0$: For $n=0$ because it starts with $w'w'^R$, for $n=1$ because it starts with $ww^R$, for $n\ge 2$ because it starts with $xx^R$.
* If $|w|=1$ then $|v|\ge 1$, say $v=xv'$ with $|x|=1$, and we have $ww^Rx^nv'\in L$ for all $n\in\Bbb N_0$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: exactly! that's why I said "I think it's impossible!" , but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Anyhow I just want to prove that the language is not regular. I preferred Pumping Lemma but it's not necessary to use this. I just want it to be proven, by Pumping Lemma or without it! Can anyone help?

Comment: @Hsm I tried (a few times!) using the pumping lemma but failed. The Myhill-Nerode theorem does the trick (see below), and given the definition of $L$ that's perhaps not surprising.

Comment: See the question [Is this language regular?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7271/is-this-language-regular/7272#7272) on cs.stackexchange and its answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the alphabet has only one symbol then $L$ is regular, so assume the alphabet contains at least two symbols, which we'll call $0$ and $1$.

For $n>0$, let $w_n = (01)^n$ and $s_n = w_n w_n^R\in L$. Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation of the Myhill-Nerode theorem:
$$
x\sim y \iff \forall z\,(xz\in L \leftrightarrow yz\in L).
$$
By the theorem, $L$ is regular *iff* $\sim$ has only finitely many equivalence classes.

Suppose $m < n$, and let $z=w_m^R$. We have $w_m z = s_m \in L$. However, if $w_n z = (01)^n(10)^m \in L$, then by definition of $L$ there are $s,t$ with $|s|>0$ such that
$$
w_n z = (01)^n(10)^m = (01)^{n-m}(01)^m(10)^m = ss^Rt
$$
But because $n>m$, there are no such $s$ and $t$, so $w_n z\notin L$ after all. So this $z$ distinguishes $w_m$ and $w_m$.

It follows that
$$
m\ne n \implies w_n \not\sim w_m,
$$
so $\sim$ has infinitely many equivalence classes, hence $L$ is not regular.

Comment: I cannot add a comment because of my reputation, sorry. But I think the answer of BrianO is not correct, again! Now I think this is incorrect: L0 = L ∩ (01)^+ (10)^+ because 0101101010 is a member of both L and (01)^+ (10)^+ but it's not a member of L0 Again, if I'm wrong, please explain! And Thank you so much for answering me! :)

Comment: This keeps some of the previous answer (the use of $01$ and $10$), but Myhill-Nerode is a much better hammer to hit the problem with.